# CSS3 @font-face causes the font file to output its sample text

Tags: css, font-face, truetype

I used the @font-face this way

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'SteelTongs';
src: url('../fonts/SteelTongs.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
 }

section.page_heading .logo a {
        font-size: 40px;
        font-family: 'SteelTongs';
        text-shadow: 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.36);
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 25px;
```

Now, what happens is the sample text normally in .ttf file shows in the logo container

Edit:
See http://www.had.omarsalim.biz

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Notice the Header

Please help

I tested in chrome and firefox

Comment: `.ttf` files don't contain sample text. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Are you *sure* you used the right font?

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help :)

I used the right font

You can check out http://www.had.omarsalim.biz to see what I am talking about

Answer (score 0):

I'm also tested with the SteelTongs web font in firefox and chrome, it is not supported,the font link is

[abstractfonts- steeltongs](http://www.abstractfonts.com/font/11551) ,U just change the font.

Comment: Yah, I changed the font and it was fine, I guess it is an issue with font support